# Use PowerShell to stop 'Default Web Site' in IIS6

Tags: powershell, iis-6

I've done several Google searches and can't find a good sample to stop/start the 'Default Web Site' (in II6) using PowerShell.

This...

```
$server = "localhost"
$siteName = "default web site"
$iis = [ADSI]"IIS://$server/W3SVC"
$site = $iis.psbase.children | where { $_.keyType -eq "IIsWebServer" 
        -AND $_.ServerComment -eq $siteName }
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330608/changing-iis6-site-home-directory-with-powershell-answered) got me started, but I can't get the 'start'/'stop' syntax right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the serverState property. A value of 2 means running and a value of 3 means stopped, you can set them this way:

### start the website

$site.serverState = 2

$site.setInfo()

### stop the website

$site.serverState = 3

$site.setInfo()

Comment: did you manage to get this working? i'm outputting the server state to host and its 2 before changing the state and then 3 afterwards (i.e. i want to stop it and restart it).. however when looking in iis, the server is still running.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use the [Adsutil.vbs Administration Script (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/d3df4bc9-0954-459a-b5e6-7a8bc462960c.mspx?mfr=true)?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/scripts/default.mspx?mfr=true. The example is in VBScript, but it's exactly the same technique in PowerShell.