# ASP.NET MVC Website Deploy

Tags: deployment, iis-7, web

We have ASP.NET MVC website deployed in IIS. Every day we keep publishing the changes into the Website. We are following the below steps

1. We build the source and get the assemblies from our local publishing server(Maintained in intranet).
2. Replace the assemblies into the website server. Here i have faced the down time.

I dont want to follow app_offiline method. Every day if we put some under maintanenence information it will be very odd for my customers.

Without downtime i need to deploy the changes.

Thanks,
Velu

Comment: Check out this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148084/how-to-deploy-an-asp-net-application-with-zero-downtime**