# Will an ASP.NET web application be temporarily unavailable while deploying via WebDeploy?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, webdeploy

I am currently using the publishing functionality in Visual Studio 2010 to publish an asp.net web app to an IIS 7.5 server, via Web Deploy. The server itself is Windows 2008 R2 server with Web Deploy 3.0 and the Web Management service installed. I am also deploying using the server's local administrator account (it is not part of a domain). I was curious as to whether or not the application/site should continue to be available to users while a deployment is in progress?

The Web Deploy functionality has worked great thus far, but I did get an error report from a user the other day where the error message specified that one of the DLLs required for the app could not be loaded, because it was in use by another process. This error occurred during a deployment.

Everything I have experienced and read so far has lead me to believe that users should see no interruption of service during a deployment, so I was surprised to see this error. I have tried scouring Google, but have yet to turn up any good information on this particular scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no magic that WebDeploy does. So yes, it is expected to have downtime.

There are ways to have zero downtime during update, they are discussed in [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/148084/706456). But you have to do some additional tricks.

#### Bonus

If you get reports from a user saying that some dll cannot be found - you have a security flaw. Never disclose such error details to the end user.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Full error messages are turned off in production, but thanks for pointing that out.