# IIS Staging and Production swap

Tags: asp.net, iis, continuous-integration, iis-8, continuous-deployment

I'm researching a way to integrate a staging environment on our IIS Server, where it is possible to warm up the application before swapping it with the production environment.

The only real solution I can find is:

1. Swapping directory settings

   - Which to me sounds like a slow process, because the IIS will have to compile and warmup the new dir after the swap. ( Am I assuming this correctly?)
2. Have two sites, and swap the bindings, after staging has been warmed up.
3. Having a load balancer, and swapping between two sites. This just seems to be overkill, since both websites would be on the same server.

The two first scenarios seem hacky, and error prone.

Obviously there must be something I am missing. So I turn to you, the experts!

Ps. We are on Windows Server 2012, IIS v8.0

Comment: are you binding on host header and ip or just ip?

Comment: @avvi We're binding on the host header, as we have multiple websites on the server.

Comment: What exactly you mean by warming up ? Like spinning the process (w3wp.exe) and loading all the libraries in the app domain ? Which typically happens for the first request after process shutdown. If this is the case why not try using application initialization module? If it is something else let me know what exactly warming up includes

Comment: If you pre-compile the app you don't need to wait for IIS to compile it :) We're using the load balancer - not just for the "warm up scenario" but the second box is being used for "disaster recovery". (So we have two boxes with identical code - warmed up before attached to load balancer), first is then used, second is resting as backup in case of hw failure.

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar We precompile aswell, but there is a 15-30 sec. period where the IIS is warming up the site. It queues up the requests, but it takes some time for it to respond to the first callers.

Comment: The simple way to do so would be to use a [load balancer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148084/how-to-deploy-an-asp-net-application-with-zero-downtime), as there is no simple way to switch 2 IIS sites. this means additional scripting/config

Comment: @bsoulier it seems that way, I have been researching it further, and tried various scripting options. I'm not searching for a simple solution, but more a correct one. But I am coming to the conclusion that it's not very feasible with an IIS server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options 1 and 2 are going to cause the iis app pool to recycle. This might or might not be a big deal depending on the type of business you run, how you handle sessions etc.

Option 3 seems like the more graceful option and gives you some flexibility if you ever want to scale out and add additional machines. And it's the easiest to explain to future developers already familiar with the pattern.

http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html

It does however require you to access your load balance via Powershell or whatever integration tool you are using which might be tricky.

Comment: I ended up using the app_offline.htm file for deployment, it is pretty fast, and gives a nice "we're updating" message to the user if they hit the page in the few ms it is there.

Load balancing is simply too complex to justify at the current time, and we just have to live with the 1-2 minutes slow-down time, when the site starts up again.