# Show “Site is being updated” when ASP.net website is being compiled

Tags: asp.net, iis, compilation

We have an ASP.net webforms website that is fairly large - on the machines we're serving it on when we update the website it can take a couple of minutes before working again as it compiles it. From what I understand about this process, this is unavoidable.

During compilation, we'll see a hundred or so timeout errors in our logs which is expected I would suppose.

Is there any way for us to serve a "Website is being updated please wait a moment" page during this process?

Comment: For saving web service lifetime, you need to use Staging-Production swapping. You have a copy of your production site on staging folder. When you need to release an update - just update your staging folder and then just swap staging with production instance. [How to do it using IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39102207/iis-staging-and-production-swap). Not an actually answer, but recommendation

Comment: It doesn't have to be a staging server, although you can use that if you have limited resources. You can also have one active and one standby server both dedicated to production use, and utilize the same strategy. Deploy to the standby side, send it a request to wake it up and trigger the compilation process, then once it's ready you swap it out to become the active node. If you already have load balanced servers, then you have enough resources for this: drain one side, deploy to that side and make it compile, then once it's good you make it the active side and drain the other side etc.

Comment: You may want to look into [blue green deployment](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html).

Comment: Have you tried app_offline or IIS application initalization https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization?